# regex to find incomplete xml tags in c#

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I'm trying to use regular expression to find incomplete xml tags that have no attributes. So far, I've managed to come up with this regex `</?\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]?:\s+)?[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!>)`, but that doesn't do the trick. 
In an xml like this one:
    `<abc>
    </abc>
    <ab>
    </ab
    <s:ab`

I want to match `</ab` and `<s:ab` (as they're both lacking ">" at the end). Is there a way to do this using regular expressions in c#?

Comment: Regex is not suitable for this - you should use an XML parser/validator.

Comment: You cannot cover all possibilities with one regular expression. You'd better follow Oded's suggestion.

Comment: I don't think there's that much possibilities. These are the kinds of tags I'm interested in: </[a-zA-Z0-9], <[a-zA-Z0-9, </[a-zA-Z0-9]:[a-zA-Z0-9]. That should be all I want to look for.

Comment: Depending on what the source documents look like I don't think Regex is necessarily bad, but I do think that the expectation of writing a single Regex to find all problems will lead to failure. Most text parsers out there that I've seen stop at the first problem they find. When that's fixed the scan begins again. Repeat until fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close. Your major problem is that the pattern backtracks when the negative lookahead fails. You can avoid that by putting the part before the lookahead in an non-backtracking atomic group: `(?>no backtracking in here)`.

For example:

```
(?xi)                   # turn on eXtended (ignore spaces/comments) and case-Insensitive mode
(?>                     # don't backtrack
  < /?                  # tag start (no space allowed after it)
  [a-z0-9]+             # tag name/space
  (?: : [a-z0-9]+ )?
  \s*                   # optional spaces
)
(?! > )                 # no ending
```

Note that this will match `<foo` in `<foo bar>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to find errors in a single xml file, try opening it in Google Chrome web browser - it will show the line where the error is.

But if you have lot's of files you have to process in code, then you'd need something more powerful than regexes.

Answer (score 0):

As people have said, this is probably a fruitless endeavor - as XML is not a regular language.  However, part of your problem is your lookahead.  You only ensure that it's not immediately followed by a closing angle bracket - which means things like `<ab` of `<abc>` will match even when you don't want them too.  so you need to include the entire tag structure in your lookahead.

To get a match for the exact data you gave, I could use the regular expression:

```
#</?([a-z]?:)?[a-z]*(?!/?([a-z]?:)?[a-z]*>)#
```

Which you can see in action [here](http://regexr.com?3436a).  The key here is to make sure that at no point can the regular expressions engine backtrack (by say, dropping one character) to validate the lookahead.  There are other ways to do this - such as [possessive quantifiers](http://regexr.com?3436g), which refuse to give up their matched token in a normal backtracking process, but the standard .NET engine doesn't support possessive matching.  It does support an atomic group - which behaves the same way, but using a group instead of a quantifier.  You can see [here](http://regexr.com?3436m) that I've wrapped the entire opening of the tag in an atomic group.  (`(?> ... )`)

```
#(?></?([a-z]?:)?[a-z]*)(?!>)#
```

You're free to enter your own regular expression for how a tag ought to be formatted, but I must say that this regular expression is already pushing the limits for readable code, and messing about with legal xml tag names is going to push it further in that direction.  Nevertheless, I hope this has helped shed some light on the error.

Comment: What's with the hashes? This isn't PHP, no need to double quote.

Comment: @Qtax It's fairly standard in Perl Compliant Regular Expressions to use a delimiter.  PHP isn't the only language that does it.  Perl (clearly) and Javascript have them built into the language (though Javascript only allows the forward slash).

Comment: You are double/nesting quoting here. This silliness is only done in PHP. Other languages have special quoting constructs (eg `/regex/`) for regex (Perl, JS, Ruby, etc), or just use regular string quotes (Java, C++, etc). In Perl you can use pretty much any character you want to quote the expression. My point is: 1) C# does not quote like that. 2) You have already quoted the expression in your markdown markup, there is no need to quote it again (in an unsupported format nonetheless). 3) Don't spread the PHP regex quoting madness

Comment: @Qtax I'm not double nesting at all - I merely used a delimiter.  I put it in a code block, but there's nothing wrong with using a delimiter to show that it's a regular expression.  It not the PHP "madness" you're complaining about.  It really helps when adding modifiers (such as case insensitivity), so you can easily separate them from the regular expression itself.  I chose not to do the forward slash because I didn't feel like escaping it in the actual regex.  I just happen to thing `#regex#xi` is easier to read than `(?xi)regex`.